# MySQL Migration Toolkit syntax error when creating Sql Server diagram object

Tags: sql-server, mysql, migration

I have another syntax error when migrating a diagram. I'm not certain this diagram is necessary, but it would be nice to have a smooth migration, and this is all that's standing in the way.

The error is: You have an error in your SQL Syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-1) NULL, PRIMARY KEY ('diagram_id'), UNIQUE INDEX 'UK_principal_name' ('pri' at line 6

And the syntax has a `VARBINARY(-1)` which I've never seen before. Is that the problem?

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Fonebook_dbo`.`sysdiagrams`;
CREATE TABLE `Fonebook_dbo`.`sysdiagrams` (
  `name` VARCHAR(128) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `principal_id` INT(10) NOT NULL,
  `diagram_id` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `version` INT(10) NULL,
  `definition` VARBINARY(-1) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`diagram_id`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `UK_principal_name` (`principal_id`, `name`)
)
ENGINE = INNODB;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VARBINARY(-1), -1 is a length of binary. Set the correct length, such 100

```
  `definition` VARBINARY(100) NULL,
```

Comment: I ended up ignoring the object altogether, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not experienced with the data type but I'm guessing that is the issue:

The permissible maximum length is the same for BINARY and VARBINARY as it is for CHAR and VARCHAR, except that the length for BINARY and VARBINARY is a length in bytes rather than in characters.

So yeah, I don't think negative 1 bytes is a valid length.